# Using variable inside sed statement

Tags: sed

I want to replace the second occurrence of 127.0.0.1 with $IP in the /etc/hosts file.

There are two occurrences of 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1       hostname.com hostname

IP=192.168.1.1
```

I am trying to use this sed expression to replace 127.0.0.1 with $IP:

```
sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s|127.0.0.1|$IP|2" /etc/hosts
```

The issue is that the $IP is not getting interpreted. How can I make the $IP to be interpreted and not replaced literally?

Comment: Show the output of `printf "%s" "$IP" | od -c`

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix is to modify your quoting:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s|127.0.0.1|'$IP'|2' /etc/hosts
```

The problem with your version is most likely that `:a;N;$!ba` is being expanded by the shell into: `:a;N;ba`. You can test this by placing `echo` in front of `sed`.

In bash, the variable `$!` contains the process ID of the most recently executed background pipeline.

Note that `.` matches any single character, not just a period, and so `127.0.0.1` matches more than you may expect.